# Blank process name in Activity Monitor on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, activity-monitor

In my activity monitor I have noticed that there is a process appearing that has no name.
It is owned by root.

[image]

How can I find out what this process is?

Answer (score 3):

Try clicking the "info" button and then running a sample on the process. For me, the process turned out to by iStatLocalDaemon.

Answer (score 1):

I usually have process like this on my "Activity Monitor" too, and there is no additional information related to it when I push the "Info" button.

First I get the PID showed at the "Activity Monitor", in your example, is

> 31602

In my case, it was the `725` PID.

I went to the "Terminal" and looked up for that PID manually, using `ps` command:

```
ps -ea | grep 725
```

The result was:

```
  725 ??         0:00.13 com.apple.activititymonitor.helper
```

Now I have an idea about what the process without name is :)

I hope this can resolves your doubts.

Best Regards.